# Unable to click on Save button for naukri.com

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

The following code is to click Save button but its not working & even error is also not displaying, I have also shared the DOM, please help I have tried classname, xpath, csslocator, Javascript to scroll down, Actions class, but still its not working for me, Please help.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='submit']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform()

  <div class="formRow">
  <div class="formRow">
  <div class="blueBut1 ml124">
  <button class="w150bt fl" type="submit" value="Save Changes">
  <a class="fl mt10 ml8" href="/Profile/view?id=&altresid=" rel="last">
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: See output of `driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@type='submit']")).length` and check if multiple elements match your description

Comment: try the xpath  //button[@value='Save Changes' and @type='submit'] or //button[@value='Save Changes']

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @value='Save Changes']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Using JSE is not a good practice. It's not a scenario that a user can perform. A better practice is to figure out what the actual problem is and solve it so that the script interacts with the page the way a user would.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the element to become clickable.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@type='submit']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this xpaths with wait

```
//button[@value='Save Changes']
//button[@value='Save Changes' and @type='submit']
```

use this code

```
WebElement submitButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Save Changes']"));
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitButton))).click();
```

or

```
WebElement submitButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Save Changes' and @type='submit']"));
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(submitButton))).click();
```